# My Mute Button Is Stopping But Not Playing

Tags: c#, playback, audio, mute

```
        SoundPlayer StartUpMusic = new SoundPlayer(Resources.Guiles_Theme);       
        private void MuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (StartUpMusic.IsLoadCompleted == true)
            {
                StartUpMusic.Stop();
                StartUpMusic.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                StartUpMusic.Load();
                StartUpMusic.Play();
            }
        }
```

This is an event triggered when the user clicks the play button. I think my condition within the if statement is not good. I basically want the sound to be muted when the button is pressed. Then I want the sound to continue when the button is pressed and the sound is already muted. What is wrong here? You time and effort are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to pause or to mute your playback?

Comment: I would like to pause it, and include some sort of check to see if the end of the sound file has been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a boolean flag to indicate if the sound is playing or not. So something like this might work:

```
private boolean isPlaying = true;
private void MuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (StartUpMusic.IsLoadCompleted)
    {
        if (isPlaying)
            StartUpMusic.Stop();
        else
            StartUpMusic.Play();
        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome your input is greatly appreciated.